# Where are the DB documents stored in DocumentDB Emulator?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I installed the sample .NET App with the [DocumentDB Emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator).

I can see the data when the app is running. Where are the DB documents (files) physically stored by the DocumentDB Emulator?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you click the DocumentDB emulator system tray icon, you'll see a menu item for resetting your data:

[image: emulator menu]

If you choose to reset your data, you'll receive a warning message, along with the location where the emulator is storing its data:

[image: location]

Comment: Well, Do you know ,there in DocumentDBEmulator folder, DB file in which file or folder is stored? I actually at the end want to know how I can import my JSON data to the DB without using any Apps except DocumentDB.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. But... it seems like you're trying to reverse-engineer the emulator. Which is not really in scope here.

Answer (score 4):

I'm late with an answer but my question was "how can I change the location?"  If you are here for the same reason https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator has this gem under `Command-line Tool Reference`:

`Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Emulator.exe [/Shutdown] [/DataPath] [/Port] [/MongoPort] [/DirectPorts] [/Key] [/EnableRateLimiting] [/DisableRateLimiting] [/NoUI] [/NoExplorer] [/EnableMongoDbEndpoint] [/?]`

and

> `DataPath`    Specifies the path in which to **store data files**. Default value is `%LocalAppdata%\CosmosDBEmulator`.    CLI example: `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Emulator.exe /DataPath=<datapath>` `<datapath>`: An accessible path.

This helped me.

Comment: i tried to run emulator with ./Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Emulator.exe /DataPath=D:\CosmosDBEmulator where D is ramdisk drive for faster startup, but it would fail with Faulting application name: Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Emulator.exe, version: 2.14.4.0, time stamp: 0x61727288
Faulting module name: ESENT.dll, version: 10.0.19041.1266, time stamp: 0xffdd8818, not sure if its ramdisk fault or emulator..

Answer (score 3):

The Azure Cosmos (DB) emulator (the renamed Document DB emulator) stores its local state in

```
$env:LOCALAPPDATA\CosmosDbEmulator
```

Or, if you're using Windows Explorer, CMD, &c.:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\CosmosDBEmulator
```

This typically resolves to a path like:

`C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\CosmosDBEmulator`

The emulator uses an opaque storage format, so you will not find JSON documents for what you've written stored in this directory. To inspect what's stored in your databases, you'll need to use the APIs or the web UI.

To launch the web UI, find the Cosmos DB Emulator icon in your [notification area](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/notification-area)/"system tray", right click on it, and select "Open Data Explorer...". This will launch your web browser to the right page. You may receive a warning about connecting to a site that is using a self-signed TLS certificate that you will need to allow/bypass/accept.

[image: Highlighting the Cosmos Emulator icon in the notification area]

[image: Showing the "Open Data Explorer..." menu item]